# How to add headers or parameters to an HTTP request handled with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, post, selenium, junit, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver for unit testing of a web application. It's used in JUnit tests Despite reading the available documentation extensively and searching around, I could not find a way to:

- Add headers to an HTTP request passed by the driver.
- Add parameters to such a request, as if the driver got his target URL after submitting a form.

It would be possible to create a test web page with an appropriate form and have Webdriver bounce off it to get those parameters automatically, but this is quite an ugly hack. I would like to avoid it, especially for the sake of test atomicity. (This is unit testing.)

Before Wendriver, I was using Spring's MockHttpServletRequest and MockHttpServletResponse to do this, which worked like a charm, but I would like to use the power of Webdriver to assert the target page's contents.

Answer (score 5):

You can try evaluating browsermob-proxy.  It helps in manipulating the headers.
https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy.  Integrating with webdriver is simple.  You just need to start the driver with the proxy values set.

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful for others who are looking for a solution

This is how I fixed the problem in my case. Hopefully, might be helpful for anyone with a similar setup.

1. Add the ModHeader extension to the chrome browser

How to download the Modheader? Link

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File(C://Downloads//modheader//modheader.crx));

// Set the Desired capabilities 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

// Instantiate the chrome driver with capabilities
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(YOUR_HUB_URL), options);
```

2. Go to the browser extensions and capture the Local Storage context ID of the ModHeader

[image: Capture ID from ModHeader]

3. Navigate to the URL of the ModHeader to set the Local Storage Context

.

```
// set the context on the extension so the localStorage can be accessed
driver.get("chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/_generated_background_page.html");

Where `idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj` is the value captured from the Step# 2
```

4. Now add the headers to the request using `Javascript`

.

```
   ((Javascript)driver).executeScript(
         "localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify([{  title: 'Selenium', hideComment: true, appendMode: '', 
             headers: [                        
               {enabled: true, name: 'token-1', value: 'value-1', comment: ''},
               {enabled: true, name: 'token-2', value: 'value-2', comment: ''}
             ],                          
             respHeaders: [],
             filters: []
          }]));");
```

Where `token-1`, `value-1`, `token-2`, `value-2` are the request headers and values that are to be added.

5. Now navigate to the required web-application.

   `driver.get("your-desired-website");`

Comment: This is not working for me. After setting when I open the extension on the browser the headers dont show up. I also believe the extension is not storing the values that I enter through the UI (extensions) in the local storage

Comment: Why do you keep spamming this same answer every where although it's not working for anyone?

Comment: what do you mean *Spamming everywhere" - Do notice that this was a 3 year old answer and it worked for me personally. It worked for others who used/configured it the right way.. May be you didn't configure it the right way. Chrome and Selenium has moved many versions after this answer. And "Everywhere" - I posted the answer in the relavent threads only in the same timeline (somewhere in Aug 2020).