# Adding cookies with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: node.js, selenium, cookies, suman

I have the following sequence of Selenium code, written with Node.js:

```
   it('tests cookies', t => {
      driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
        console.log('all cookies => ', cookies);
      });
      driver.manage().addCookie({name:'foo', value: 'bar'});
      driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
        console.log('all cookies => ', cookies);
      });
      driver.manage().deleteCookie('foo');
      return driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
        console.log('all cookies => ', cookies);
      });
    });
```

and I get this output:

```
all cookies =>  []
all cookies =>  []
all cookies =>  []
```

anybody know why the addCookie functionality wouldn't work? I am not sure I understand why this wouldn't yield some cookies in the cookie jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that cookie domain is not defined. You need to navigate to some URL before you can work with cookies. Try adding `driver.get('<some_url>')` before getting all the cookies **and after** setting a new cookie.

```js
it('tests cookies', t => {
      driver.get('127.0.0.1'); // <-- This will set the domain
      driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
        console.log('all cookies => ', cookies);
      });
      driver.manage().addCookie({name:'foo', value: 'bar'});
      driver.get('127.0.0.1'); // <-- Navigate again after setting a new cookie
      driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
        console.log('all cookies => ', cookies);
      });
      driver.manage().deleteCookie('foo');
      return driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
        console.log('all cookies => ', cookies);
      });
    });
```

See this as well: [Selenium JS add cookie to request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305660/selenium-js-add-cookie-to-request)

Comment: thanks, I am looking here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_Options.html

Comment: for some reason this call: driver.manage().addCookie({name: 'cec_user_id', value: val, secure: true, httpOnly: true}); yields:

Comment: all cookies =>  [ { path: '/',
    domain: 'cdt-server',
    name: 'cec_user_id',
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    hCode: -810793967,
    value: 'alexamil',
    class: 'org.openqa.selenium.Cookie' } ]

Comment: any idea why that cookie is neither secure nor httpOnly?

Comment: Secure cookies can only be set for HTTPS connections

Comment: As far as I know `httpOnly` means that the cookie was set by the server rather than the client side javascript. There was a known issue with Chromedriver always returning false for `httpOnly`. Check that you are using the latest version.

Comment: yeah so there's a problem with this - what if I cannot get the domain, until I have a cookie in hand?