# Request header for cucumber tests

Tags: capybara

is it possible to set the http request header with capybara? i have seen several posts like this

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.headers = { 'Accept-Language' => 'de' }
Capybara.current_session.driver.header('Accept-Language', 'de')
```

but doesn't seem to work. I am trying to set the following header

```
X-TEST-IP : 127.0.0.1
```

That when i visit my site, I am authenticated. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: sorry for the later reply, i was using chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

You’re using selenium which doesn’t provide a way to set headers. It is possible through middleware or a programmable proxy - see [setting request headers in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645093/setting-request-headers-in-selenium) , although you’re probably better off just using the test mode of whatever auth library you are using (devise, etc)