# How to set headers in python selenium firefox webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, header, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm doing IP bypass programming through a site called ProxyMesh.

Below is the code I created.

```
def ip_bypass_proxymesh():
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", '1xx.2xx.1xx.30')
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 312xx)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", '45.32.2xx.x6')
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 31xxx)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path='D:\webdrivers/geckodriver')
    return driver
```

I'd like to add a header that specifies the country,

------>>>   header = {'X-ProxyMesh-Country: US'}

but I have no idea. (I searched for this one, but since I am a beginner, I do not understand.)

I'd appreciate it if you let me know.

https://docs.proxymesh.com/article/7-request-response-headers#x-proxymesh-country

Thank you very much.

Comment: selenium doesn't support it, however there is a work around using some browser add ons. Reference:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645093/setting-request-headers-in-selenium