# Webpage Is Detecting Selenium Webdriver with Chromedriver as a bot

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, bots

I am trying to scrape https://www.controller.com/ with python, and since the page detected a bot using `pandas.get_html`, and requests using user-agents and a rotating proxy, i resorted to using selenium webdriver. However, this is also being detected as a bot with the following message. Can anybody explain how can I get past this?:

> Pardon Our Interruption...
>   As you were browsing www.controller.com something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:
>   You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.
>   You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser.
>   A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running. Additional information is available in this support article.
>   To request an unblock, please fill out the form below and we will review it as soon as possible"

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
#options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.controller.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have mentioned about `pandas.get_html` only in your question and `options.add_argument('headless')` only in your code so not sure if you are implementing them. However taking out minimum code from your code attempt as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.controller.com/')
  print(driver.title)
  ```

I have faced the same issue.

- Browser Snashot:

[image: controller_com]

When I inspected the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) it was observed that the website refers the **distil_referrer** on **`window.onbeforeunload`** as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="">
    window.onbeforeunload=function(a){"undefined"!==typeof sessionStorage&&sessionStorage.removeItem("distil_referrer")};
</script>
```

Snapshot:

[image: onbeforeunload]

This is a clear indication that the website is protected by **Bot Management** service provider [**Distil Networks**](https://www.distilnetworks.com/) and the navigation by *ChromeDriver* gets detected and subsequently **blocked**.

---

### Distil

As per the article [There Really Is Something About Distil.it...](https://www.forbes.com/sites/timconneally/2013/01/28/theres-something-about-distil-it/#6e1881e438b9):

> Distil protects sites against automatic content scraping bots by observing site behavior and identifying patterns peculiar to scrapers. When Distil identifies a malicious bot on one site, it creates a blacklisted behavioral profile that is deployed to all its customers. Something like a bot firewall, Distil detects patterns and reacts.

Further,

> `"One pattern with Selenium was automating the theft of Web content"`, Distil CEO Rami Essaid said in an interview last week. `"Even though they can create new bots, we figured out a way to identify Selenium the a tool they're using, so we're blocking Selenium no matter how many times they iterate on that bot. We're doing that now with Python and a lot of different technologies. Once we see a pattern emerge from one type of bot, then we work to reverse engineer the technology they use and identify it as malicious".`

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [Distil detects WebDriver driven Chrome Browsing Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Akamai Bot Manager detects WebDriver driven Chrome Browsing Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872920/clicking-on-get-data-button-for-monthly-settlement-statistics-on-nseindia-com-do/59874462#59874462)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the fix mentioned in the discussion you sent me and that worked! With removing the cdc_ portion from chromedriver. Shouldnt be too long before Distill responds to this workaround dont you think?

Answer (score 4):

Finally solved the problem and headless mode works as well.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
```

Answer (score 3):

Distil can detect if you are headless by doing some fingerprinting using html5 canvas. They also check things like browser plugins and user-agent. Selenium sets some browser flags that are also detectable.