# What is the difference in accessing Cloudflare website using ChromeDriver/Chrome in normal/headless mode through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare, google-chrome-headless

I have a question about `--headless` mode in Python Selenium for Chrome.

Code

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

 CHROME_DRIVER_DIR = "selenium/chromedriver"

 chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
 chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
 chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
 chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
 chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # # Bypass OS security model
 chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
 chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

 browser = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_DIR, options=chrome_options)

 browser.get("https://www.manta.com/c/mm2956g/mashuda-contractors")
 print(browser.page_source)
 browser.quit()
```

When I'm remove `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")` all working good, but with this `--headless*` got next issue

```
Please enable cookies.

Error 1020 Ray ID: 53fd62b4087d8116 • 2019-12-04 11:19:28 UTC

Access denied

What happened?
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.

Cloudflare Ray ID: 53fd62b4087d8116 • Your IP: 168.81.117.111 • Performance & security by Cloudflare
```

What is the difference for normal mode and `--headless`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code, removed the optional *arguments* and added a few *arguments* to execute the test as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.manta.com/c/mm2956g/mashuda-contractors")
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html class="js" lang="en-US" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;"><!--<![endif]--><head>
  <title>Access denied | www.manta.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>


  <!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->



  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cf-wrapper">
      <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
      <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
        <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
      <h1>
        <span class="cf-error-type" data-translate="error">Error</span>
        <span class="cf-error-code">1020</span>
        <small class="heading-ray-id">Ray ID: 53fd7c2fca12d5fc • 2019-12-04 11:36:52 UTC</small>
      </h1>
      <h2 class="cf-subheadline">Access denied</h2>
        </div><!-- /.header -->

        <section></section><!-- spacer -->

        <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
      <div class="cf-columns two">
        <div class="cf-column">
          <h2 data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
          <p>This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.</p>
        </div>


      </div>
        </div><!-- /.section -->

        <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper">
    <p>
      <span class="cf-footer-item">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong>53fd7c2fca12d5fc</strong></span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator">•</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Your IP</span>: 123.201.54.43</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator">•</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>

    </p>
  </div><!-- /.error-footer -->


      </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
    </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window._cf_translation = {};


  </script>



  </body></html>
  ```

---

### Analysis

From the extracted page source it is pretty clear using **`--headless`** argument you are reaching to a page with:

- Heading as: *Access denied | www.manta.com used Cloudflare to restrict access*.
- Some information: *What happened?*: *This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.*

---

### Conclusion

The **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session is getting detected as a **BOT** and the navigation is **blocked**.

---

### Outro

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is there a version of selenium that is not detectable ? can selenium be truly undetectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528631/is-there-a-version-of-selenium-that-is-not-detectable-can-selenium-be-truly-un/56529616#56529616)
- [Chrome browser initiated through ChromeDriver gets detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832413/chrome-browser-initiated-through-chromedriver-gets-detected/52833487#52833487)
- [Webpage Is Detecting Selenium Webdriver with Chromedriver as a bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984185/webpage-is-detecting-selenium-webdriver-with-chromedriver-as-a-bot/54984891#54984891)

Comment: `options.add_argument("--headless")` without this argument all is working fine on my end, so why `--headless` generate `Cloudflare` protection alert? All the same in code just one argument... Is any way to avoid it? Use `--headless` in the same as normal?

Comment: @МаксимДихтярь Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: You didn't answer the question, *why* is it blocked?

Comment: @Guy Perhaps you need to revisit the answer specifically the **Analysis** and**Conclusion** section.

Comment: @DebanjanB I did. The analysis section is in the question, just not in html format. The conclusion is correct, but doesn't explain why it works without `--headless`.

Comment: @Guy You still need to read the discussions in details which I have provided in the **Outro** section for a better understanding.

Answer (score 11):

It's the HTTP `User-Agent` header that Cloudflare doesn't like.

To get around this issue, simply change your `user-agent` chrome option (below code is for Selenium in Python):

```
option.add_argument('--headless')
option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work not - March 2022

Answer (score 6):

I tested using this server-side script:

```php
<?php
echo "<pre><code>";
var_dump($_SERVER);
echo "</code></pre>";
?>
<script>
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName('code')[0];
    for(var prop in window.navigator){
        var str = JSON.stringify(window.navigator[prop])
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + "window.navigator." + prop + " = " + str + "\n";
    }
    var skip_props = ['parent', 'top', 'frames', 'self', 'window'];
    for(var prop in window){
        if (skip_props.indexOf(prop) > -1) { continue; }
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + "window." + prop + " = ";
        var str = JSON.stringify(window[prop])
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + str + "\n";
    }
</script>
```

I loaded this page using ChromeDriver, with and without using `--headless`, and printed the output using `print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('code').text)`. I then diff-ed both outputs.
Here's the differences I found:

- HTTP `Accept-Language` header: `en-US,en;q=0.9` vs `en-US`
- HTTP `User-Agent` header: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36` vs `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36` (Note the `HeadlessChrome` mention in the second string.)
- Javascript `window.navigator.plugins`: `{"0":{"0":{}},"1":{"0":{}},"2":{"0":{},"1":{}}}` vs `{}`
- Javascript `window.navigator.mimeTypes`: `{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{}}` vs `{}`
- Javascript `window.outerWidth`: `1367` vs `0`
- Javascript `window.outerHeight`: `641` vs `0`

Of note: in the Python script you posted, you are missing a few lines, to remove the `window.webdriver` property (without this, it is trivial for the server to detect you are using WebDriver) [[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040904/432306)]:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Cloudflare aims to block bots. They assume headless browser is used by data scrapers so they are blocking it. from Cloudflare [What is Data Scraping?](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/bots/what-is-data-scraping/)

> *A headless browser is a type of web browser, much like Chrome or Firefox, but it doesn’t have a visual user interface by default,
>   allowing it to move much faster than a typical web browser. By
>   essentially running at the level of a command line, a headless browser
>   is able to avoid rendering entire web applications. Data scrapers
>   write bots that use headless browsers to request data more quickly, as
>   there is no human viewing each page being scraped.

Comment: Blocking of Bots is not restricted to Cloudflare. It's a common practice among numerous anti scrapping sites. Besides Cloudflare, there is Distil, Akmai, etc

Comment: @DebanjanB Did I say it's unique to Cloudflare? the OP asked about specific site protected by Cloudflare.