# Ebay website hangs after login button clicked - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, bots

I have written the following code to login to a website. So far it simply gets the webpage, accepts cookies, but when I try to login by clicking the login button, the page hangs and the login page never loads.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException


# Accept consent cookies
def accept_cookies(browser):
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gdpr-banner-accept"]').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Cookies already accepted')
        

# Webpage parameters
base_site = "https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/"

# Setup remote control browser
fireFoxOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
#fireFoxOptions.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/home/Webdriver/bin/geckodriver',firefox_options=fireFoxOptions)
browser.get(base_site)
accept_cookies(browser)

# Click login pop-up 
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Einloggen')]")[1].click()
```

*Note: There are two login buttons (one popup & one in the page), I've tried both with the same result.*

I have done similar with other websites, no problem. So am curious as to why it doesn't work here.

Any thoughts on why this might be? Or how to get around this?

Answer (score 3):

I modified your code a bit adding a couple of optional arguments and on execution I got the following result:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver.get("https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='gdpr-banner-accept']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Einloggen')]"))).click()
  ```
- Observation: My observation was similar to your's that the page hangs and the login page never loads as shown below:

[image: ebay-kleinanzeigen.de]

---

### Deep Dive

While inspecting the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the webpage you will find that some of the `<script>` and `<link>` tag refers to *JavaScripts* having keyword **dist**. As an example:

- `<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="/static/js/lib/node_modules/@ebayk/prebid/dist/prebid.10o55zon5xxyi.js"></script>`
- `window.BelenConf.prebidFileSrc = '/static/js/lib/node_modules/@ebayk/prebid/dist/prebid.10o55zon5xxyi.js';`

This is a clear indication that the website is protected by **Bot Management** service provider [**Distil Networks**](https://www.distilnetworks.com/) and the navigation by *ChromeDriver* gets detected and subsequently **blocked**.

---

### Distil

As per the article [There Really Is Something About Distil.it...](https://www.forbes.com/sites/timconneally/2013/01/28/theres-something-about-distil-it/#6e1881e438b9):

> Distil protects sites against automatic content scraping bots by observing site behavior and identifying patterns peculiar to scrapers. When Distil identifies a malicious bot on one site, it creates a blacklisted behavioral profile that is deployed to all its customers. Something like a bot firewall, Distil detects patterns and reacts.

Further,

> `"One pattern with Selenium was automating the theft of Web content"`, Distil CEO Rami Essaid said in an interview last week. `"Even though they can create new bots, we figured out a way to identify Selenium the a tool they're using, so we're blocking Selenium no matter how many times they iterate on that bot. We're doing that now with Python and a lot of different technologies. Once we see a pattern emerge from one type of bot, then we work to reverse engineer the technology they use and identify it as malicious".`

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [Unable to use Selenium to automate Chase site login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)
- [Webpage Is Detecting Selenium Webdriver with Chromedriver as a bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984185/webpage-is-detecting-selenium-webdriver-with-chromedriver-as-a-bot/54984891#54984891)
- [Is there a version of selenium webdriver that is not detectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528631/is-there-a-version-of-selenium-webdriver-that-is-not-detectable/56529616#56529616)

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

# options.add_argument("--headless")

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"C:\Users\DIPRAJ\Programming\adclick_bot\chromedriver.exe")

stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )

url = "https://bot.sannysoft.com/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer. It may help the other readers to the problem to easily understand your approach.