# Python Selenium automatic booking bot

Tags: python, selenium, bots, captcha

I wanted to write a bot, which will automatically find canceled driving tests and rescheduled your test date to this date, in order to decrease the time of waiting.

I decided to use selenium on python to perform this. However, despite all my tries, I couldn’t get the browser to stop detecting the bot, so there is always CAPTHCA for this bot.

Can someone suggest a potential solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium-powered browser windows are by default (required by law in some regions) marked automated, and websites that have bots disabled on their platforms can easily detect it and prevent any kind of automation. There are some workarounds but these workarounds are not very reliable as these get patched quite often.

You can try these resources if they still work:

1. [Webpage Is Detecting Selenium Webdriver with Chromedriver as a bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984185/webpage-is-detecting-selenium-webdriver-with-chromedriver-as-a-bot)
2. http://php8legs.com/en/php-web-scraper/51-how-to-avoid-selenium-webdriver-from-being-detected-as-bot-or-web-spider
3. [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/41220267)