# Suddenly Firefox cannot load custom fonts from the same site anymore with CORS error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.8

I use Selenium Webdriver in a python script to download sites from my webpage and convert them into PNGs:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = Options()
options.headless = False
SITE = "http://localhost/something_I_want_to_convert_with_hi-resolution.html"
DPI = 2.5
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("layout.css.devPixelsPerPx", str(DPI))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get(SITE)
...
```

This worked fine until last month when I still used Ubuntu 20.04. It created the images with the right font [like this](https://cards.incantata.de/cdn/orig/card_135.png).

I guess exactly since the Ubuntu upgrade Firefox cannot load the custom fonts, I have included via css in my site, anymore and it loads the default fonts instead now.

What could have changed that behaviour? Was there a recent update in Ubuntu 20.10 that changed the behaviour of Firefox?

I get this error in the console which is strange:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/css/fonts/kramer__.TTF. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

it is strange, because the font is in the same domain (`localhost`) so there shouldn't be a CORS error.

The same site works fine in Chrome and loads the fonts. Also in Waterfox-classic it loads the fonts just fine.

I would like to add something like:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

but I serve the site locally with [ZeroNet](https://zeronet.io/), which is html-, CSS- and JS-only, so I think, I cannot change the headers sent.

I tried in firefox `about:config`:

- disable `content.cors.disable` (empty string)
- `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` False
- `privacy.file_unique_origin` False

but none of those had any effect.

If I install the [access-control-allow-origin addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/access-control-allow-origin/) and enable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` it also works fine, (I added that as a **workaround** below.)

How do I set Firefox to ignore the Cross-Origin Request?

Comment: If you want to set headers. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919307/7906655

Comment: @mangupt, can you provide an answer how to send a header, so that firefox will ignore any CORS errors?

Comment: But I think there must be another problem with my Firefox, I have the same CORS errors on youtube now: The page loads, but when it tries to start the video, I get a CORS error in the console there too

Comment: Maybe try refreshing or reinstalling.

Comment: I don't want to repost the answer from above stack post. Can you please check that? You might need to use Selenium Wire instead to be able to set. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/15647143/7906655 why Selenium won't help you set headers.

Answer (score 1):

might be your container/zeronet updated or firefox updated after that you are facing issue

For Temporary Workaround in chrome for localhost you can add — disable-web-security  while starting chrome

in firefox you can do the following :

about:config -> security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy -> false

Comment: I need to use Firefox. And I tried `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` already without effect

Answer (score 0):

#### Workaround

1. go to `about:preferences` and create a new empty profile
2. change to that profile in a new window
3. install the **Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin** there

now change your python code to use that new profile with

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("/home/your_user/.mozilla/firefox/your_new_profile")
```

This will start the profile, wich already has installed the addon that fixes the CORS problem.