# How to open url in browser with custom headers using python

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I have tried using the webbrowser module, with the code below but want to set custom headers such as:

```
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1'
```

Here's the code I have right now:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=TEST123")
```

I'm okay with using another library too. Essentially I want my python script to open a url in my default browser with custom headers.

Comment: @Sujay I would like my default browser to open that url with the custom header I am setting.

Comment: Do you need to specifically open it in the browser? Or are you okay with making a request (if you're scraping, or downloading, or whatever)? Passing headers with the `webbrowser` module isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) for the webbrowser module doesn't provide information on how to access underlying headers. It seems this is not possible. As stated in the documentation:

> The webbrowser module provides a high-level interface to allow displaying Web-based documents to users.

1. **Use an extension/addon on your browser**

You could use your current code and install an extension on your browser like [simple-modify-headers](https://github.com/didierfred/SimpleModifyHeaders) extension for Firefox or Chrome. (The extension can be installed via [this link](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/simple-modify-header/) for Firefox and via [this link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-modify-headers/gjgiipmpldkpbdfjkgofildhapegmmic) for Chrome).

It's very easy to change header values with these extensions. For simple-modify-headers:

[image: simple-modify-headers settings]

*There are lots of other extensions/addons out there but I can't name all of them here. Just search "Modify Header extension addon [your browser]" to find one that fits your needs.*

2. **Use another library**

You could use [Selenium Wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire). This library might be exactly what you want:

> Selenium Wire extends Selenium's Python bindings to give you access to
> the underlying requests made by the browser. You author your code in
> the same way as you do with Selenium, but you get extra APIs for
> inspecting requests and responses and making changes to them on the
> fly.

**Example:**

Install via pip:

```
pip install selenium-wire
```

Download and install a driver for your browser: [Chrome Driver](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads) or [Gecko Driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

*Choose a version compatible with your browser.*

*To get your browser version: on Firefox go to `menu > help > about`; on Chrome go to `menu > about chrome`*

Install OpenSSL:

```
# For apt based Linux systems
sudo apt install openssl
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#installation) for more details on the installation.

> ```
> from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire
>
> # Create a new instance of the Chrome driver (or Firefox)
> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>
> # Create a request interceptor
> def interceptor(request):
>     del request.headers['User-Agent']  # Delete the header first
>     request.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Custom User-Agent'
>
> # Set the interceptor on the driver
> driver.request_interceptor = interceptor
>
> # All requests will now use 'some_referer' for the referer
> driver.get('https://www.bing.com/search?q=TEST123')
> ```

I derived the code above from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919307/15016163).

You can see [Selenium's documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads) for other browsers, if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution however the driver is opening the browser in a weird test environment that doesn't serve my purposes. Let me know if there is a way to get it to open in my actual browser.

Comment: @Hammaad, I updated my answer. Does the first item meet your needs?

Comment: Your extension idea worked great! I was able to toggle that on manually then run my script which opened the pages with the modified header.