# Setting selenium request header

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to set the request header in selenium. For one or another reason, I am not able to find *how* to set such a header.

If I  read correctly, this is not possible and I would need an extension in Chrome to set the request header: [setting request headers in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645093/setting-request-headers-in-selenium)

Is this answer still up to date? And are there other ways to implement a header in a get request using selenium?

I am using node js and selenium to build a web scraper.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium does not support as of today, setting headers.
It is not generally something a user does.

You can also try [Mechanize](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
It's really old, and I am not sure if it has Python3 support -- but you can set the headers. A long time ago I used it for web-scraping.

However, you might get away by using good ol' requests and something like [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).