# How to use referer in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, referer

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


if __name__ == "__main__":

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("User-Agent=" + user_agent)
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1400, 1000')
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])

    chrome_ver = chromedriver_autoinstaller.get_chrome_version().split('.')[0]
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(f'./chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)


    driver.get('https://www.google.com')

    headers = {
        'Referer':'https://www.google.com/search?q=test'
    }

    driver.get('http://www.test.com', headers=headers)
```

err ===>   headers=headers

I want to put a referer on the [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) page.

Comment: What do you mean by "err ===> headers=headers"? Does this generate an error message and traceback? If so, what does it say?

Comment: You probably want to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919307/12444149)