# How to get source code with headers request from protected dynamic javascript

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, dom, get, request-headers

I want to obtain the source code from a dynamic JavaScript website, it is necessary to send the request with headers.

I attempted to do this using Selenium, but I am unsure how to include the headers in the request.

I try to use headers=headers, but it marks it as an unexpected argument.

```
from selenium import webdriver


def download_page(url):
    # Enviar los headers necesarios para que la página se cargue correctamente
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "example",
        "token": "example"
    }

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get(url, headers=headers)

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    source = driver.page_source

    driver.close()

    return source


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://example.com/"

    source = download_page(url)

    print(source)
```

Comment: You can't. Selenium does not have an API to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting request headers in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645093/setting-request-headers-in-selenium)

Comment: Maybe https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12892/how-to-send-basic-authentication-headers-in-selenium

Comment: @ScaryWombat That is actually useful (even is for java). I modified the code and it works correctly.
```chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_service = ChromeService("chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)

headers = {}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
    "Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders", {"headers": headers}
)
url = ""
driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

content = driver.page_source
```
 
I hope this will be useful to someone else