Add request header before opening a webpage
There is request header (which works like VPN) I need to add before I open a webpage.
I've been trying different approaches like JS executor, Modheader, Proxy and nothing really helped. Only with JS executor I was able to add this request header but only after I've opened a webpage what is unacceptable.
Maybe some know some approaches that works as expected?
//some code to add request header

driver.get("https://myWebsite");


you should be able to do this with Bidi interface... see here for C# version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76146335/4744568
